# UICollectionView with a custom data Structure

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, shortcut

I am trying to create a collection view similar to Apple's shortcuts app. I was able to create the cells themselves but I am having a hard time create an individual data cell (if that makes sense). My goal is to have each cell display a title, subtitle, and possible a play button.
Right now, I am having a hard time figuring out where I am going wrong with my constraints or possible my data structure (its crashing on the background and the text isn't showing on the colored cell).

```
struct customData {

    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    
    //Mark : All Cards
    fileprivate let data = [
        
        customData (title: "iOS", subtitle: "12 Tips"),
        customData (title: "iPadOS", subtitle: "11 Tips"),
        customData (title: "macOS", subtitle: "10 Tips"),
        customData (title: "tvOS", subtitle: "19 Tips"),
        customData (title: "watchOS", subtitle: "18 Tips"),
        customData (title: "Accessories", subtitle: "17 Tips"),
        
    ]
    
    //MARK : Properites
    let cellId = "Cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        setupCollectionView()
        setupNavigationBarController()
    }
    
    //MARK : Setup Methods
    fileprivate func setupNavigationBarController() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationItem.title = "Lists"

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        }

    }
    
    fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .red
        collectionView.register(customCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    }
    
    //MARK : CollectionView Delegate Methods
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 6
        return data.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! customCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 2) - 20, height: 110)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    }

}

class customCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
    var data: customData? {
        didSet {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            listName.text = data.title
            subName.text = data.subtitle
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate let listName: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel ()
        iv.textColor = .white
        iv.font = UIFont(name: "Times" , size: 12)
        return iv
        
    }()
    
    fileprivate let subName: UILabel = {
        let iv = UILabel ()
        return iv
        
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCell()
        
        contentView.addSubview(listName)

        listName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
       listName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        listName.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
       listName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    // MARK: Setup Cell
    fileprivate func setupCell() {
        roundCorner()
        gradientBackgroundColor()
        setCellShadow()
    }
    
    // MARK: Methods
    func setCellShadow() {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        self.clipsToBounds = false
    }
    
    func cellRandomBackgroundColors() -> [UIColor] {
        //Colors
        let red = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9654200673, green: 0.1590853035, blue: 0.2688751221, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.7559037805, green: 0.1139892414, blue: 0.1577021778, alpha: 1)]
        let orangeRed = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9338900447, green: 0.4315618277, blue: 0.2564975619, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8518816233, green: 0.1738803983, blue: 0.01849062555, alpha: 1)]
        let orange = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9953531623, green: 0.54947716, blue: 0.1281470656, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.9409626126, green: 0.7209432721, blue: 0.1315650344, alpha: 1)]
        let yellow = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9409626126, green: 0.7209432721, blue: 0.1315650344, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8931249976, green: 0.5340107679, blue: 0.08877573162, alpha: 1)]
        let green = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3796315193, green: 0.7958304286, blue: 0.2592983842, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.2060100436, green: 0.6006633639, blue: 0.09944178909, alpha: 1)]
        let greenBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2761503458, green: 0.824685812, blue: 0.7065336704, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6422213912, blue: 0.568986237, alpha: 1)]
        let kindaBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2494148612, green: 0.8105323911, blue: 0.8425348401, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6073564887, blue: 0.7661359906, alpha: 1)]
        let skyBlue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.3045541644, green: 0.6749247313, blue: 0.9517192245, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.008423916064, green: 0.4699558616, blue: 0.882807076, alpha: 1)]
        let blue = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.1774400771, green: 0.466574192, blue: 0.8732826114, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.00491155684, green: 0.287129879, blue: 0.7411141396, alpha: 1)]
        let bluePurple = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.4613699913, green: 0.3118675947, blue: 0.8906354308, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.3018293083, green: 0.1458326578, blue: 0.7334778905, alpha: 1)]
        let purple = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7080290914, green: 0.3073516488, blue: 0.8653779626, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.5031493902, green: 0.1100070402, blue: 0.6790940762, alpha: 1)]
        let pink = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9495453238, green: 0.4185881019, blue: 0.6859942079, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.8123683333, green: 0.1657164991, blue: 0.5003474355, alpha: 1)]
        
        let colorsTable: [Int: [UIColor]] = [0: red, 1: orangeRed, 2: orange, 3: yellow, 4: green, 5: greenBlue, 6: kindaBlue, 7: skyBlue, 8: blue, 9: bluePurple, 10: bluePurple, 11: purple, 12: pink]
        
        let randomColors = colorsTable.values.randomElement()
        return randomColors!
    }
    func gradientBackgroundColor() {
        let colors = cellRandomBackgroundColors()
        self.contentView.setGradientBackgroundColor(colorOne: colors[0], colorTow: colors[1])
    }
    func roundCorner() {
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
}
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: "(its crashing on the background " So there is a crash message in console? Which is... ?

Comment: its the constraints on list name. I tried changing them multiple times. The only time it goes away (the crashing), is when I comment out the constraints for it. Though it doesn't show my data still

Comment: And there is no error message in the console when it’s crashing?

Comment: Besides saying it can't satisfy those constraints, no other errors.

Comment: You should be getting some feedback for the crash, add it to your question. If it's only the warning then you can fix it by my post below.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the warnings that say constraint cannot be satisfied you should set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `listName` to `false`.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupCell()

    contentView.addSubview(listName)
    listName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Add this
    listName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    listName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    listName.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    listName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
}
```